# Is it possible to rewrite to a shorter url in next js?

Tags: next.js

Suppose I have this page structure in Next Js which is statically generated:

/[category]/[subCategory]/[slug]

Which renders: fruit/banana/bananaPost

I would want the url to be shorter and only say: /[slug] —> /bananaPost

I read something about rewrites on next js docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [catch-all segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments). Dynamic Segments can be extended to catch-all subsequent segments by adding an ellipsis inside the brackets `[...slug]`. This means that your URL could then be one of the following while still being valid:

- /fruit/banana/bananaPost
- /fruit/banana
- /fruit

Note that when using catch-all segments they always need to be at the end of an segment, meaning something like `/[...slug]/[id]` is not possible. Another important point is that your slug parameter will be returned to you in form of an array, heres an example when visiting the url `/fruit/banana/bananaPost` while naming the folder `[...slug]`:

```
interface Props {
  params: { slug: string[] };
}

export default async MyCatchAllPage(props: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  console.log(props.params) // logs: { slug: ["fruit", "banana", "bananaPost"] }
  // ...
}
```